# Request Traker 4.0.4 Change Language

Tags: rt

I need to change the language of Request Tracker 4.0.4 to Portuguese.
I tried setting the LexiconLanguage in the RTConfig_Site.pm file with this code:
Set(@LexiconLanguages,qw(pt_PT)); 
but it doesn't work.

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be indicative of a few things I can see. There's a few things to check first though - what was the result you expected when changing the setting of LexiconLanguages? Were you thinking that all users would see RT in Portuguese immediately or that Portuguese would be one of/the only option for users to choose from? When you say it doesn't work, what happens? Do you still see everything in English or is there an error message/log message showing up?

Here's the most likely cause I can think of:

You were expecting that the language for already existing users would just change and that, with no additional changes everything would be portuguese. This is not the case. The LexiconLanguages setting controls which of the po files are loaded (and thus available for users to choose from). In this case all your users languages are probably still set to en. You could run a query to update the lang field for all users to pt_PT to solve this.